# I am getting the Error "ERROR: column "distance" does not exist LINE 2: FROM "gps" WHERE distance < 30 ; "

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.6

I have this piece of SQL code:

```
 create table gps(id integer, latitude double, longitude double);
insert into gps(id, latitude, longitude) values(1, 2, 3);
insert into gps(id, latitude, longitude) values(1, 1, 1);
insert into gps(id, latitude, longitude) values(1, 1, 1);
insert into gps(id, latitude, longitude) values(1, 30, 1);
```

but i noticed the code runs fine on MYSQL, but throws an error on postgres.

```
 ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist
LINE 6: HAVING  distance < 30
```

an alternative would be

```
SELECT * , latitude + longitude AS distance
FROM "gps"
GROUP BY id
HAVING  latitude + longitude < 30
```

but this can get messy specially if the code is longer that latitude + longitude

I have looked for a way to by pass this but with no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this might help you:

```
SELECT *  FROM  
(
   SELECT id, latitude + longitude AS distance 
   FROM gps
) as a  
GROUP BY 1,2  
HAVING distance < 30;
```